Solution to a First-Order PDE Using the Lagrange method and division by zero
I need to find a solution for the following PDE:
$$
 \begin{cases} 
      y u_x - x u_y = 0 \\
      u(x, 0) = x^2 & ,x \in \mathbb{R} \\
   \end{cases}
$$
My attempt:
I started by using the Lagrange method:
$$A(x,y,u)u_x - B(x,y,u)u_y = C(x,y,u)$$
$$\frac{dx}{A(x,y,u)} = \frac{dy}{B(x,y,u)} = \frac{du}{C(x,y,u)}  $$
Therefore:
$$
\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{-x} \space\space\space \setminus \cdot(-xy) \\
\\
-x dx = y dy \space\space\space \setminus \int \\
\\
-\frac{x^2}{2} = \frac{y^2}{2} + C$$
Which simplifies to:
$$x^2 + y^2 = C_1$$
Based on this characteristic equation and the face that $C(x,y,u)=0$, I proposed that the solution $ u $ can be expressed as a function of $ x^2 + y^2 $:
$$ u(x, y) = F(x^2 + y^2) $$
Given the initial condition, I deduced:
$$ u(x, 0) = F(x^2) = x^2 $$
This implies:
$$ F(t) = t $$
Final solution is:
$$ u(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 $$
Questions:

Verification: At the beginning of the solution I divided by $x,y$. Does my solution $ u(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 $ correctly solve the PDE across the entire plane, including the origin where $ x = 0 $ or $ y = 0 $?
Method of Characteristics: How should I handle the division by zero that arises when using the Lagrange  method? Specifically, what approach should be taken when $ x = 0 $ or $ y = 0 $ to ensure the solution is valid everywhere?

I am seeking feedback on the correctness of my approach and any suggestions on how to address potential issues with the method used, particularly concerning divisions by zero.


Verification: At the beginning of the solution I divided by $x,y$. Does my solution $ u(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 $ correctly solve the PDE across the entire plane, including the origin where $ x = 0 $ or $ y = 0 $?

Put your solution into the original PDE and check.

Method of Characteristics: How should I handle the division by zero that arises when using the Lagrange  method? Specifically, what approach should be taken when $ x = 0 $ or $ y = 0 $ to ensure the solution is valid everywhere?

$$\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{-x} =\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{du}{0}=$ variable which implies $du=0$ then :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{-x}$
$$x^2+y^2=c_2$$
So one have two independent characteristic equations. The general solution of the PDE is :
$$\Phi(c_1,c_2)=\Phi\big(u,(x^2+y^2)\big)=\text{constant}.$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.
Or on another form :
$$c_1=F(c_2)=u=F(x^2+y^2)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function.
That is what you already correctly found. As well for the further calculus according to the boundary condition.

But how can I explain the division by zero at the beginning? Doesn't it affect the values of which the solution is valid for?

No need to divide by $0$. The system of characteristic ODEs can be expressed as : $$\begin{cases} dx=y:ds\dy=-x:ds\du=0:ds\end{cases}$$ Thus $du=0$.

I understand. It does solve my problem. Thank you.
